# no exact match with indexOf

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I seem to be having a problem with indexOf to get an exact match.
I have an API that searches for items in MongooseDB where the search query matches. This works only to some extend.

Here is the used code:

```
exports.searchItems = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.searchQuery);
    if (!req.query || !req.query.searchQuery) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message:"'searchQuery' param should be passed with valid query!"
        });
    }

    Item.find().then(itemsList => {
        if(!itemsList) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "No Items found for search query: " + req.query.searchQuery
            });
        }
    
        var items = [];
        const queryVal = req.query.searchQuery;
    
        itemsList.forEach(function(item){
            if(item) {              
                if(JSON.stringify(item).indexOf(queryVal) > -1) {
                    items.push(item);
                }
            }
        });
    
        res.status(200).send({items});      
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occured while fetching all items!"
        });
    });
};
```

Now let's say the search query is "LO_Buehne2" the result will be:

```
{"items":[{"_id":"5f9fcf321337250c6815ac47","ort":"LO_Buehne2","bezeichnung":"ABB Beleuchtungsstärkemessgerät","seriennummer":"H42805104","pruefdatum":"01.01.2021","ausgeliehen":false,"ausleih_datum":"","ausleih_name":"","ausleih_nummer":"","rueckgabe_datum":"","einsatzort":"","notiz":"","url":"http://192.168.1.48/fileserver/uploads/asfgasfasf.jpg","createdAt":"2020-11-02T09:19:46.287Z","updatedAt":"2021-03-19T10:41:45.591Z","__v":0}]}
```

This is correct since there is only one item with "ort":"LO_Buehne2"

But if I search for LO_Buehne the result will be this:

```
{"items":[{"_id":"5f8fe281ee35da3068b0ac49","ort":"LO_Buehne","bezeichnung":"Panasonic Akku- u. Schlagschrauber","seriennummer":"9090442 / 9080163","pruefdatum":"01.01.2021","ausgeliehen":false,"ausleih_datum":"","ausleih_name":"","ausleih_nummer":"","rueckgabe_datum":"","einsatzort":"","url":"http://192.168.0.65/fileserver/3.jpg","createdAt":"2020-10-21T07:25:53.855Z","updatedAt":"2021-03-19T10:37:17.774Z","__v":0,"notiz":""}
...
...
...
{"_id":"5f9fcf321337250c6815ac47","ort":"LO_Buehne2","bezeichnung":"ABB Beleuchtungsstärkemessgerät","seriennummer":"H42805104","pruefdatum":"01.01.2021","ausgeliehen":false,"ausleih_datum":"","ausleih_name":"","ausleih_nummer":"","rueckgabe_datum":"","einsatzort":"","notiz":"","url":"http://192.168.1.48/fileserver/uploads/asfgasfasf.jpg","createdAt":"2020-11-02T09:19:46.287Z","updatedAt":"2021-03-19T10:41:45.591Z","__v":0}
```

As you can see, it finds all items with "ort":"LO_Buehne" but it will also find that one item with "ort":"LO_Buehne2".

Question is...why? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Because `LO_Buehne` is a substring of `LO_Buehne2`

Comment: Right. but shouldn't indexOf search for exact matching cases? How would I get exact matches?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an exact match you have two solutions.

1. Regex magic
2. Work with javascript objects and `===` instead of JSON strings.

#### 1. Regex Solution

```js
const search = 'LO_Buehne';

const reg = new RegExp(`"${search}"`);

console.log(reg.test('{opt: "LO_Buehne2"}')); // fail
console.log(reg.test('{opt: "LO_Buehne"}')); // works
```

This is simple [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that looks to see if the search term you're looking for is surrounded by `"` (double quotes). This will only work for values in double quotes.

#### 2. Working with objects

```js
const data = {"items":[{"_id":"5f9fcf321337250c6815ac47","ort":"LO_Buehne2","bezeichnung":"ABB Beleuchtungsstärkemessgerät","seriennummer":"H42805104","pruefdatum":"01.01.2021","ausgeliehen":false,"ausleih_datum":"","ausleih_name":"","ausleih_nummer":"","rueckgabe_datum":"","einsatzort":"","notiz":"","url":"http://192.168.1.48/fileserver/uploads/asfgasfasf.jpg","createdAt":"2020-11-02T09:19:46.287Z","updatedAt":"2021-03-19T10:41:45.591Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5f8fe281ee35da3068b0ac49","ort":"LO_Buehne","bezeichnung":"Panasonic Akku- u. Schlagschrauber","seriennummer":"9090442 / 9080163","pruefdatum":"01.01.2021","ausgeliehen":false,"ausleih_datum":"","ausleih_name":"","ausleih_nummer":"","rueckgabe_datum":"","einsatzort":"","url":"http://192.168.0.65/fileserver/3.jpg","createdAt":"2020-10-21T07:25:53.855Z","updatedAt":"2021-03-19T10:37:17.774Z","__v":0,"notiz":""}]}

const search = 'LO_Buehne';

const res = data.items.filter(item => {
  return new Set(Object.values(item)).has(search);
});

console.log(res);
```

This solution consists in doing a strict equal to see if the value exists. In the above example I use a combination of [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), but it's completely doable with [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) / [Array#findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

i.e.:

```
const res = data.items.filter(item => {
  return Object.values(item).findIndex(value => value === search) > -1;
});
```

Comment: It seems like he specifically wants the `ort` property so Object.values is probably a bad idea. why not: `data.items.find(({ort}) => ort === search)`

Comment: @xdumaine I would tend to disagree, if they were specifically checking `ort`'s values they wouldn't  `JSON.stringify` the javascript object. I think they're searching in general for matches accross all properties.

Comment: Based on this sentence: `As you can see, it finds all items with "ort":"LO_Buehne" but it will also find that one item with "ort":"LO_Buehne2".`

Comment: I do actually only want to find values from the "ort" property

Comment: Im still having a little trouble understand nodejs. I see that once an item matches queryVal that item gets pushed into items. But what about itemsList? Does it even get filled? Could someone alter my original code so that searching though the "ort" value finds an exact match? Thanks!

Comment: Could someone perhaps post a solution using my originally posted code? That would be great!